# how to update the state before rendering the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, setstate

I have this app that adds "persons" to a "phonebook", and the user can update the person's phone if the person already exists.
but I want to know to handle the problem of when the person was already deleted (i open two tabs and delete a phone in one tab, and I try to "update" it in the second tab)

I have a `persons.js` which handles all HTTP requests (I'm using axios)
and a `PersonNotification.js` which tell the user if the phone is "added"  or "updated" or "doesn't exist anymore"
and all the main functionalities are inside the `App.js`

*here is my code*

**persons.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
const URL = "http://localhost:3001/persons";

const getPersons = () => {
  return axios.get(URL).then((res) => res.data);
};

const addPerson = (person) => axios.post(URL, person);
// this is where i have the probelm (i think)
const updatePerson = (person, number, setErrMsg) => {
  axios
    .put(`${URL}/${person[0].id}`, {
      name: person[0].name,
      number,
    })
//i wanted the change the state of the App.js from this line after there is an error
    .catch((err) => setErrMsg("err"));
};

const deletePerson = (person) => axios.delete(`${URL}/${person.id}`);

export { getPersons, addPerson, deletePerson, updatePerson };
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  getPersons,
  addPerson,
  deletePerson,
  updatePerson,
} from "./services/persons";
import Filter from "./components/Filter";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import Phonebook from "./components/Phonebook";
import PersonNotification from "./components/PersonNotification";
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState([]);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState("");
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");

  // fetching the data from json-server (i,e: db.json)
  useEffect(() => {
    getPersons().then((res) => setPersons(res));
  }, []);
  // function that fires after the submit
  const personsAdder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const personsObject = { name: newName, number: newNumber };

    //checking if the name exists
    const nameChecker = persons.filter(
      (person) => person.name === personsObject.name
    );
    console.log(errMsg);
    if (nameChecker.length > 0) {
      const X = window.confirm(
        `${personsObject.name} already exists do you want to update the number`
      );

      if (X === true) {
        // updating the number if the user confirmed
        updatePerson(nameChecker, newNumber, setErrMsg);
        const personsCopy = persons;
        const index = personsCopy.indexOf(nameChecker[0]);
        personsCopy[index] = {
          id: personsCopy[index].id,
          name: personsCopy[index].name,
          number: newNumber,
        };

        setPersons([...personsCopy]);
        setNewName("");
        setNewNumber("");
        //the function the shows the notification for 5 seconds after the content was updated
        const notificationSetter = () => {
          let X = "";
          if (errMsg.length > 0) {
            X = `you can't update${nameChecker[0].name} because it doesn't exist anymore`;
          } else {
            X = `${nameChecker[0].name} was updated`;
          }
          setNotification(X);

          setTimeout(() => {
            setNotification("");
            setErrMsg("");
          }, 5000);
        };
        notificationSetter();
      }
    } else {
      //adding a new user if the name was not already in the phonebook
      setPersons(persons.concat(personsObject));
      addPerson(personsObject);
      setNewName("");
      setNewNumber("");
      //the function the shows the notification for 5 seconds after the content was added
      const notificationSetter = () => {
        setNotification(`${personsObject.name} was added`);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setNotification("");
        }, 5000);
      };
      notificationSetter();
    }
  };

//... there is still more down here; i don't know if i should copy paste all my code
```

**PersonNotification.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./PersonNotification.css";

const PersonNotification = ({ notification, errMsg }) => {
  if (errMsg.length > 0) {
    return <h1 className="err">{notification}</h1>;
  }
  if (notification.length === 0) {
    return <></>;
  } else {
    return <h1 className="notification">{notification}</h1>;
  }
};

export default PersonNotification;
```

PS:
this the [github](https://github.com/oussamaghrib/fullStackOpen-exercises/tree/master/part2/phonebook) folder of this app.
this is an exercise from fullstackopen.com so i hesitate a bit before posting my question here, but i spent more than 4 hours on this problem
all i want is to figure out how to update the state of "errMsg" earlier, and i think after that everything will become easy

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Even I am not quite clear on what you want to know? But if your concern is what to do when a contact is already deleted from the list and someone else tries to delete it again, then you can make a service request on delete action and send proper response from the backend that this contact doesn't exist anymore and finally display a proper message on the UI that this contact has already been deleted.

Comment: no, i want to have "personNotification" render an "error" to the screen. which says something like "this component is already deleted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part should help you enough to go further.

**persons.js**

```
const updatePerson = (person, number) => {
  const request = axios
    .put(`${URL}/${person[0].id}`, {
      name: person[0].name,
      number,
    });
  return request.then(response => response.data)
};
```

**App.js**

```
if (X === true) {
  const notificationSetter = (X) => {
    setNotification(X);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setNotification("");
      setErrMsg("");
    }, 5000);
  };
  // updating the number if the user confirmed
  updatePerson(nameChecker, newNumber, setErrMsg)
  .then(data => {
    notificationSetter(`${nameChecker[0].name} was updated`);
    console.log('persons :>> ', persons);
    console.log('data :>> ', data);
    
    const personsCopy = persons;
    const index = personsCopy.indexOf(nameChecker[0]);
    personsCopy[index] = {
      id: personsCopy[index].id,
      name: personsCopy[index].name,
      number: newNumber,
    };
    
    setPersons([...personsCopy]);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    notificationSetter(`you can't update ${nameChecker[0].name} because it doesn't exist anymore`);
    getPersons().then((res) => setPersons(res));
  })
  setNewName("");
  setNewNumber("");
}
```

Comment: i think that's what i needed, because i couldn't catch the error in app.js!

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your update. i've made a lot of changes to my App.js now, but i will check you update for a bit, thank you sir!

Comment: wow, thank you, i've never thought of just changing the state inside the catch. you really saved me for going insane. i can't thank you enough!